# How to link a static library conditionally in visual studio

Tags: c++

I'd like to link my code to a static library conditionally, that is depending on a compilation flag.

Is there anyway I can do that in C++?

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Makefiles?

Answer (score 8):

You may do that using a pragma:

```
#ifdef YOUR_CONDITION
#pragma comment (lib, "YourLibrary.lib")
#endif
```

Comment: This is not standard; this is MSVC++ specific.

Comment: @BillyONeal `visual studio` is in the title of the question.

Comment: @Alexy: Fair enough. :)